# Windows Server 2012 R2 Hyper V keep changes done under checkpoint

Tags: hyper-v, windows-server-2012, hyper-v-manager

What I'm trying to do is, I create a checkpoint then uninstall some software, and install some new software, on success I want to keep/move changes to parent drive and then delete the checkpoint.

Initially i Applied the changes but came to know that in fact its reverting (Undo) changes, after some google I came across Merge option under Disk Edit, so I merged checkpoint with parent disk but when i load the windows not only again it was at previous state but also software to be uninstalled was corrupted. Any idea where I'm doing mistake. Thanks.

Comment: It would seem that you misunderstand the purpose of checkpoints. I strongly suggest you read up on what Checkpoints are and how they are to be used before continuing to use them.

Comment: You are right, by deleting it merges, as you advised for further understanding i found these links helpful [Checkpoint overview](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn818483%28v=ws.11%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#BKMK_consider) and [using checkpoints](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/user-guide/checkpoints)

Comment: Do not use the word "merge" to describe what you're doing, because that is not what you are doing. Language is important for communication, memory, and understanding. Using the incorrect terms causes trouble with all of these. The correct term is "Delete" because it accurately describes what you are supposed to do with a Checkpoint you no longer need. "Merge" is incorrect because it means something that you never do to Checkpoints. You either delete the Checkpoint or you return to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, if your system is working OK after you have made post-Checkpoint changes, you just want to DELETE the checkpoint.

Applying a Checkpoint takes the computer BACK to the state of the Checkpoint.

As I mentioned in my comment above, I highly recommend that you do further research on Checkpoints in Hyper-V to gain a better understanding of what they are and how they are designed to be used.